# FloatingActionButton and weird Behavior

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I got some strange things happening when using CoordinatorLayout.Behavior with a FloatingActionButton.

Here is a snippet:

```
public class BottomFloatingActionButtonBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {
    public BottomFloatingActionButtonBehavior() {
    }

    public BottomFloatingActionButtonBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        return (dependency instanceof BottomNavigation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        if (dependency instanceof BottomNavigation) {
            BottomNavigation bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigation) dependency;
            int height = bottomNavigation.getNavigationHeight() - bottomNavigation.getBottomInset();
            float offset = bottomNavigation.getTranslationY() - height;
            child.setTranslationY(offset);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

When using this behavior i get weird margins added to the button:
[image: Margins on first frame]

Then, when hiding the button and showing again (navigating between fragments) margins increase, but only once (do not get increased after each iteration):
[image]

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigation
            android:id="@+id/navigation_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bbn_appbar_behavior"
            app:bbn_entries="@menu/activity_main_navigation" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_behavior="it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation.BottomFloatingActionButtonBehavior"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fa_plus_white_24dp"
            app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

What am i doing wrong? What is this behavior?
The most interesting is that if i change my super class to FloatingActionButton.Behavior then all margins are gone even after switching fragments (show/hide sequence):
[image]

But this class controls the snackbar by itself so it won't work for me.

This was tested using latest (and previous also) support lib: 25.2.0 on Nougat and KitKat versions. The difference is - on KitKat there is no "second shift phase". The margins show up from the start.

Comment: did you try to put `app:useCompatPadding="false"`?

Comment: also do you really need behavior for such simple case? why not to use vertical linear layout for these 2 and get everything done on the regular layout phase?

Comment: Thanks. It helps on Nougat, but not on KitKat. Any other suggestions perhaps?

Comment: As regarding using linear layout. My layout has a "dynamic" app bar and bottom bar (they react on scrolling). Also i need to react on snackbar. Not sure if linear layout would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:minWidth` and `android:minHeight` to `0dp`.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_behavior="it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation.BottomFloatingActionButtonBehavior"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fa_plus_white_24dp"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"/>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help.